# How to match and extract value between two dataframes?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dfs:

```
df1:

col1      col2
text        1 

df2:

col1
text 123
```

I want to see if value in df1.col1 is in df2.col1, and if yes the value is present, I want to pull out value of df2.col1 into new column in df1.

updated df1:

```
col1      col2     col_extracted
text        1         text 123
```

The most I can figure out is to do a string match and get a boolean value back, like so:

```
df1['col1'].isin(df2['col1'])
```

However since I am doing partial string match I am getting a FALSE on the match.

Comment: How long are your dataframes?

Comment: @QuangHoang df1 is one row by 15 columns, df2 is 151 rows with 1 column. 

Why does length of df matter?

Comment: Because string search is slow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked for lengths of dataframes because searching/matching multiple string patterns is generally slow. You data is pretty small, so it wouldn't be a problem. Here's a solution:

```
pd.concat((df1, 
           df2[df2['col1'].str.contains(df1.col1.iloc[0])]
               .add_suffix('_extracted')
          ), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2 col_extract
0  text     1    text 123
```

Comment: I get error `error: multiple repeat`, I am working on another solution if possible.

Comment: @RustyShackleford since your `df1` is one row, see my updated answer.